# How to add a table in a pdf file using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
doc.addPage();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');

doc.save('test.pdf');
```

This code is working...But I need a table inside this code to print ...

Comment: this is not java question, it is javascript question

Comment: yhh...this is a javascript question

Comment: so move it to the javascript tag